# Media Widgets not working after ajax call after WP 4.8 updates

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have recently updated new version wordpress 4.8 for my site. And having following issue.

As WP 4.8 new version has updated text widget and media widget such as audio, video. I want to load these widget script on popup form using ajax.

My issue is on click Text widget edit button, ajax function is run which will call specific widget form and inside ajax function i have used callback function to call the form all fields of widget.

For media widgets such as audio, video on ajax call inside popup form, the widgets form is not displayed and is showing blank as you can see on below screenshot.

Video and audio widget

[image]